# wamp php5.3.5 mssql_connect() Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using WampServer Version 2.1, php5.3.5 , Apeache2.2.17
I could not use mssql_connect(), "mssql_connect() Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()"
I went through googling but still not found solution.

- I have tried install SQLSRV30 and configure as tutor but still no luck,
- I also tried  copy this ntwdblib.dll (version 2000.80.194.0) to directories php5.3.5/ext and still no luck.

kindly help me.

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php)

> These functions allow you to access MS SQL Server database.
>   This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.
>   SQLSRV, an alternative driver for MS SQL is available from Microsoft: » http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx.

Comment: So no other solution beside SQLSRV because it need to modified code start with prefix sqlsrv_

Answer (score 1):

First download SQLSRV20.EXE from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)
Put the file "php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll" in your "wamp\php\ext" folder.

In php.ini add this line: extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll

Restart apache.

Then you should be able to connect with:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database" => "dbname", "UID" => "username", "PWD" => "password", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$con = sqlsrv_connect("ipaddress", $connectionInfo);
if( $con === false )
{
  die('Not working: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
}
```

Comment: I still got error message "Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()";

Comment: Hi sir... i also have the problem like you.... so could you tell me what is the old version of php and wamp?

Comment: ask i remember wamp that had logo with white color. (currently is red)

Answer (score 1):

There is no x64 support for drivers microsoft's sqlsvr drivers. installing the 32 bit version of wamp may work for you.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f8bb1ec9-eae1-4bd9-bf71-f2f732f00def/cant-connect-using-64-bit-versions-of-php-and-apache-extension-wont-even-load