# wamp php5.3.5 mssql_connect() Fatal error

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

I am using WampServer Version 2.2, php5.4.3 , Apeache2.2.22 I could not use mssql_connect(), "mssql_connect() Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()" I went through googling but still not found solution.

Comment: You need to enable mssql in wamp extensions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wamp php5.3.5 mssql\_connect() Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql\_connect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029626/wamp-php5-3-5-mssql-connect-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-conn)

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to use PDO which supports ms sqlserver and other databases, you can use the syntax
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
or you can refer the documentation https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the MS SQL Drivers installed. You can check this with `phpinfo()`;

On Linux you need `mssql.so` or `sybase.so` With debian its `apt-get install php5-sybase`

For windows take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc793139%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Drivers need to be configured for `PHP` to find the function

```
mssql_...
```

You could also look at `PDO DB` classes as they can connect to any `DBS`, you need the drivers installed tho.